# how to create a monthly array between two dates in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have a model that have the following input:

```
monthly income: 100
start date: 31/03/2020 (created with DateField)
end date: 24/7/2020 (created with DateField)
```

I want to obtain the following QuerySet:

```
[0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

that is the 12 months and the respective income amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## simple, use lambda and map

```
f = lambda m:income if m in range(start.month, end.month+1) else 0
months = [m for m in range(1,13)]
result = list(map(f, months)]
```

Comment: result = [income if m in range(start.month, end.month+1) else 0 for m in range(1,13)]